# TextView not starting from right side in RTL Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a text view inside a linear layout. The text view inside is not starting from right side when in RTL Layout. I tried adding text alignment. It was not working. Is there any changes which I could make in the xml to fix this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!-- $Id: $ -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/list_background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="Sample text"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_bottom"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp16"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium"
        app:fontType="bold" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp16"
        android:background="@color/divider" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have you tried gravity?

Comment: Yes, tried that. Not working

Comment: android:textDirection="locale"
android:textAlignment="gravity"